Does the Bible truely promote Slavery in Exodus 21:20-21 & Leviticus 25:44-46?
I recently had a discussion here where the claim was made, that the Bible "promotes Slavery".
This claim was backed by Exodus 21:20-21 & Leviticus 25:44-46.
Exodus 21:20-21:

20 “When a man strikes his slave, male or female, with a rod and the slave dies under his hand, he shall be avenged.
21 But if the slave survives a day or two, he is not to be avenged, for the slave is his money.

Leviticus 25:44-46

44 As for your male and female slaves whom you may have: you may buy male and female slaves from among the nations that are around you.
45 You may also buy from among the strangers who sojourn with you and their clans that are with you, who have been born in your land, and they may be your property.

My Understanding of the promotion of slavery means the endorsement, encouragement, or support of the institution or practice of slavery. Slavery is a system in which individuals are owned by others, deprived of personal freedom, and compelled to perform labor or services against their will.
My attempt to show that the Bible does not endorse or encourage slavery would be:

In the case of Exodus: slavery was ingrained in every culture at that time, and this rule tried to lower the brutality and deadlyness of slavery at that time.
I would argue that Matthew 22:36-40 trumps the promotion of slavery.


There are very many Qs here, based on the Exodus 21 text (and more Qs on related OT bits about slavery). Your Q has already been answered on here, see the list on the right-hand-side, plus e.g. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/76318/exodus-2120-21-law-of-striking-a-slave?rq=1 Further, a hermeneutic answer on the verses in Q is needed, not opinions about the general topic of slavery. Arguments for and against slavery in the OT would close this Q down as outside the scope of this Hermeneutics site. Can you adjust your Q accordingly?

@Anne I edited the question a bit. The difference between my question and the one you cited is that here I am asking if the bible promotes slavery and the question you cited is asking what the law of beating slaves exactly means. Do you conclude that the Bible promotes/endourses slavery because of that law or does it not?

Yes, you have, but if you check the Hermeneutic list of Qs on the verses about slavery which you ask about, you will see I only gave one example. Such verses in the OT have been asked about a huge number of times, so this might be classified as a 'duplicate' by the Mods. As I don't know Hebrew I cannot enlighten you on the actual verses, and as this site is not for opinions on topics, I will not answer your Q to me. The topic of slavery in the OT is massive but Jesus came to set the captives free. I will say no more.

It must be admitted that the Bible endorsed slavery, both in OT and NT times. By "endorsed" I mean "officially permitted." In some cases it even encouraged the taking of slaves, especially during war. On the other hand, the Bible also gives divine sanction to slaves removing themselves from bondage, the most notable example being the Exodus, in which a whole population of enslaved people are depicted as escaping from Egyptian slavery with God's help.
Also note Jer. 34:

8 This is the word that came to Jeremiah from the Lord after King
Zedekiah had made a covenant with all the people in Jerusalem to
proclaim freedom: 9 Everyone must free their Hebrew slaves, male and
female, so that no one should hold another Judahite in servitude.

The NT adds the idea the slaves and their masters are equal in the sight of God.
Galatians 3:28

There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free
person, there is not male and female; for you are all one in Christ
Jesus.

A similar attitude is expressed in the OT, in the commandment that slaves are to be treated as part of the Covenant community (Ex. 12:44).
Conclusion: Many volumes have been written on this topic. The bottom line is that Bible endorsed slavery in some verses but encouraged slaves to liberate themselves as well. It also emphasized the humane treatment of slaves compared to other cultures, considering them as members of the religious community. As with many issues, the Bible is a two-edged sword that can be wielded by advocates on either side of the controversy.

We have to keep in mind that God bound himself in a covenant relationship to a sinful people. As a result he has a less than ideal starting point with which to shape the people. From there the laws evolve to add further protections, a tradition starting with Moses in Deuteronomy.
To start with we have to drop the mental model we have of  term “slavery” as it carries a lot of unfortunate baggage from the transatlantic slave trade.
With that in mind, we know that “slavery” for fellow hebrews was a voluntary and temporary way for those who were down on their luck to be taken care of:

Leviticus 25:39-42: "If your brother becomes poor beside you and
sells himself to you, you shall not make him serve as a slave: he shall be with you as a hired servant and as a sojourner. He
shall serve with you until the year of the jubilee. Then he shall go
out from you, he and his children with him, and go back to his own
clan and return to the possession of his fathers. For they are my
servants, whom I brought out of the land of Egypt; they shall not be
sold as slaves."

Egyptian bondage was a stark reminder for the Israelites on the darkness of slavery. God through Moses reminds them of this as to the reasons for the laws protecting slaves.

Deuteronomy 15:12-15: “If any of your people—Hebrew men or women—sell
themselves to you and serve you six years, in the seventh year you
must let them go free. And when you release them, do not send them
away empty-handed. Supply them liberally from your flock, your
threshing floor and your winepress. Give to them as the Lord your God
has blessed you. Remember that you were slaves in Egypt and the Lord
your God redeemed you. That is why I give you this command today.”

They were permitted slaves from other nations, but they were not to be mistreated:

Leviticus 25:44-46:“Your male and female slaves are to come from the
nations around you; from them you may buy slaves. You may also buy
some of the temporary residents living among you and members of their
clans born in your country, and they will become your property. You
can bequeath them to your children as inherited property and can make
them slaves for life, but you must not rule over your fellow
Israelites ruthlessly.”


Exodus 21:26-27: "If a man hits a male or female slave in the eye and
destroys it, he must let the slave go free to compensate for the eye.
And if he knocks out the tooth of a male or female slave, he must let
the slave go free to compensate for the tooth."

This next passage seems harsh but the idea is the slave owner now has to take care of the slave, and lose money while they wait for the slave to recover. This deterred mistreatment because it costs the owner.

Exodus 21:20-21: "Anyone who beats their male or female slave with a
rod must be punished if the slave dies as a direct result, but they
are not to be punished if the slave recovers after a day or two, since
the slave is their property."

So, slavery was permitted, yes but there was an intentional setting apart from the nations. It was not to be the brutal form of slavery that so readily comes to our minds. Slave owners were held accountable for harming their slaves through restitution and loss of wages.
To get a sense for how this was received consider this verse:

Exodus 21:5-6: “But if the servant declares, ‘I love my master and my
wife and children and do not want to go free,’ then his master must
take him before the judges. He shall take him to the door or the
doorpost and pierce his ear with an awl. Then he will be his servant
for life.”

So this form of slavery was so different that there were even provisions for slaves to stay on for life. There were even provisions for sheltering runaway slaves!

Deuteronomy 23:15-16: “If a slave has taken refuge with you, do not
hand them over to their master. Let them live among you wherever they
like and in whatever town they choose. Do not oppress them.”

So biblical “slavery” is not what we think. Not only that but Jesus brought a “New Torah” which considers slaves as being equal in the kingdom of God:

Galatians 3:28: “There is neither Jew nor Gentile, neither slave nor
free, nor is there male and female, for you are all one in Christ
Jesus.”


Colossians 3:11: “Here there is no Gentile or Jew, circumcised or
uncircumcised, barbarian, Scythian, slave or free, but Christ is all,
and is in all.”


1 Corinthians 12:13: “For we were all baptized by one Spirit so as to
form one body—whether Jews or Gentiles, slave or free—and we were all
given the one Spirit to drink.”


Philemon 1:16: “No longer as a slave, but better than a slave, as a
dear brother. He is very dear to me but even dearer to you, both as a
fellow man and as a brother in the Lord.”


In theology there is a notion of divine "oikonomia" - dispensation, which means that all-good and all-wise God does not treat all humans with the same measure, but apportions His commandments and goodness to their conditions. That's why He gave a commandment "tooth for tooth, eye for eye", not because He is cruel and endorses vengeance, but because at that cruel times the prescribe vengeance was the only means to curb and check injustice and violence, for a perpetrator was meant to be stopped by a fear that his wrongdoing would be paid by the same coin.
Similarly, it is not that God endorses slavery, but in the ancient society which treats slavery as a part and parcel of civilization, introduces commands and regulations that humanizes the institution of slavery. However, this humanization is never static, it has a ferment of dialectics in it, led by Holy Spirit (the insight embraced in philosophy by Hegel), and thus, society changes in the course of history and eventually slavery becomes obsolete.

Although I agree with this historical argument, it only would work if the Bible gives a reason that slavery (at least by implication) should not be promoted and that reason is biblically "stronger" than the mentioned sources. What biblical source would you use in this case?

@telion you think that Bible should give reason that slavery should not be promoted only because you are infected by modern Western arrogance of demanding even divine prophets to comply to modern Western mindset and formats, very narrow and flat ones, for that matter; you are not the only victim, I too am.

...what? Are you now arguing in favor of slavery, because of the infection of Western thinking? Also, I reject slavery because it contradicts the love for others that is promoted by Christianity, not because the Western majority rejects it. Western thinking would also allow abortion, with which I do not agree for example.

"However, this humanization is never static,... eventually slavery becomes obsolete." That slavery becomes obsolete or abolished is a speculative prediction. There are many incentives to have slaves, so any society can decide to go for slavery unless it has a reason not to. Since the question was regarding the Bible the reason I am asking for is for a biblical reason against the promotion of slavery, otherwise it follows that as a Christian there is not reason not to have slaves.

@telion Bible is a mystery and vortex of paradoxes that eludes limited categories of Western modern shallow schooling systems that undeservedly call themselves “education”. Epictetus was a slave but was freer than Voltaire with his much more limited and one-faceted brains to say nothing about such inellectual dwarfs (in comparison with the slave Epictetus) as J.S. Mill - another poisoner of our minds.

Answer
The Bible does not truly promote slavery anywhere in it but “allows” it to continue in a more humane way. However, it has laid principles in place which will help any thinking person to advocate for abolishing slavery. (This is what happened in actual history when Christians abolished slavery).
Explanation
Neither God the Father nor Jesus Christ the Lord has tried to revolutionize the present Age through any action. Jesus simply did the groundwork through His Word and Sacrifice for a future Revolution in the coming Age when He will establish a World Government.
The future Revolution in the coming Age will be so thorough that even the wolf, the leopard, the lamb and the lion all will live together!

“And the wolf shall live with the lamb; and the leopard shall lie with
the kid; and the calf and the young lion and the fatling together; and
a little boy shall lead them” (Isaiah 11:6).

Again:

“The wolf and the lamb shall feed as one; and the lion shall eat straw
like the ox. And dust is the food of the snake. They shall not do
evil nor destroy in all My holy mountain, says Jehovah” (Isaiah
65:25).

Such will be the power of the coming future Revolution “when there is no longer any distinction between Gentiles and Jews, circumcised and uncircumcised, barbarians, savages, slaves, and free, but Christ is all, Christ is in all” (Col 3:11).
But, why doesn’t God revolutionize the present Age? Why doesn’t He abolish slavery in the present Age?
Because, Satan is the God of this present Age!
He is called the “god” or the “ruler” of this world!
The Scripture says:

“the god of this age has blinded the thoughts of the unbelieving,
so that the brightness of the gospel of the glory of Christ who is the
image of God, should not dawn on them” (2 Cor 4:4).

Even Jesus Himself acknowledges this:

“I shall no longer speak many things with you, for the ruler of this
world is coming, and he has nothing in Me” (John 14:30).

This is why the Scripture calls the present world as evil:

“and the whole world lies in the evil” (1 John 5:19).


“an evil and adulterous generation” (Mat 12:39).

Thus:

“whoever wants to be a friend of this world is an enemy of God”
(James 4:4).

So, Jesus is not going to “mend” or “repair” the present world or Age:

“A bruised reed He shall not break, and a smoking wick He shall
not quench” (Isaiah 42:3).

Jesus confirmed this, when He said:

“You will always have the poor with you” (Mat 26:11).

(This shows that the current evil system will not change until the Second Advent).
But He is going to usher in a brand New Age:

“For, behold, I create new heavens and new earth. And the former
things shall not be recalled” (Isaiah 65:17).

Slavery in the Scripture = Employer-Employee Relationship
Our problem is that we project our concept of the Trans-Atlantic slavery system into the Bible (Eisegesis) which is quite absent in it.
Actually, the Bible gives rules of an employer-employee relationship.
The best example is the slave of Abraham. The latter requests him to take an oath (Gen 24:2). The slave had “in his hand”, “all his master’s goods” (verse 10). So, clearly, the slave is the steward and he is sent to seek a bride for Isaac, with “vessels of silver and vessels of gold and garments” and “precious things” (verse 53).
This is hardly the slavery system we are so familiar with!
Who, in the modern world, will give a full 24 hour rest compulsorily to any slave? Yet, we read in Exodus:

“and the seventh day is a sabbath to Jehovah your God; you shall not
do any work, you, and your son, and your daughter, your male
slave and your slave-girl, and your livestock, and your stranger who
is in your gates” (Exo 20:10)
“so that your male slave and your
female slave may rest like yourself” (Deut 5:14c).

Why is it so?

“And remember that you were a slave in the land of Egypt” (Deut 5:15).

Jubilee Year
Besides, the 50th year was a Jubilee year with no farming and other agricultural activities. This will give the slaves practically a free year-long comfort.

“and you shall make the fiftieth year holy, one year. And you shall
proclaim liberty in the land to those living in it; it shall be a jubilee to you. And you shall return every man to his possession; yea,
you shall turn back each to his family. It is a jubilee, the fiftieth
year; it is a year to you. You shall not sow, nor reap that which
grows of itself, nor gather from its unkept vines” (Lev 25:10-11).

Provision
Again, there is provision for the servants who are mistreated by their employers who are cruel:

“If slaves run away from their owners and come to you for protection,
do not send them back. They may live in any of your towns that they choose, and you are not to treat them harshly” (Deut
23:15-16).

Furthermore, it seems the slaves or more correctly servants could make complaints to their masters:

“When any of my servants (slaves) complained against me, I would
listen and treat them fairly. If I did not, how could I then face God?
What could I say when God came to judge me? The same God who created
me created my servants also” (Job 31:13-15).

Conclusion
The Bible does not promote slavery. It provides for an employer-employee relationship with a more humane approach in the evil present Age.
Even in our modern world, there are numerous cases where employers behave harshly with their employees.
The Scripture does not look for a system change but a heart change in this current Age. There is going to be both a system change and heart change in the coming better Age.

The European form of slavery has never been supported by the Holy Bible.
The European change slavery to something cruel, evil and disgustingly ugly.
The true meaning of Slavery that is supported by Scripture refers to a form of servitude. During the era of the Law of Moses, (Torah Laws), an eye for an eye. Slavery was a way to pay a debt owed through servitude to prevent bodily injury or death. However, it goes further by stating that during the year of Jubilee that Slave must be set Free.
Therefore, what the Europeans has done through their legalization of slavery in the United States of America was unjustly evil and cruel because no debt was owed by those who were enslaved. If so, according to the Holy Bible, after the 7th year was reached Jubilee commands that the servitude must end.
It is important to acknowledge that word meanings changes from one era to another- depending on who has the means to destroy the lives of people through mass slaughter.

Hi Deborah, welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange - thanks for contributing! Please do take the Site Tour to learn more about how it all works here. Your answer does not really provide a clear answer to the question and needs more references so that it's clear how you have arrived at your conclusion from these passages.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Deborah! We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs.  We're passionate about high quality answers. We look for scholarly answers show research done on the topic. Consider adding citations, quotations, and reliable sources.


Paul states Christians are not to be apart of the slave trade:  (I Tim. 1:10) ἀνδραποδισταῖς lit. men stealing or men kidnappers.

Slavery is condemned broadly under commandment "Thou shall not steal." All Christians are not to take our neighbors person, property or money by force or dishonest dealings, but help him keep his own individual life, and protect his property and business.

In James 5:1-6, slavery is condemned as "theft of labor." "Theft of labor" is one of two sins that cry out to God. (The other is murder in Gen. 4). It is a grievous sin. Why? It destroys human creativity. Each person is uniquely created by God with specialized gifts in intellect, talents and abilities. A slave is forced to give up what God has uniquely gifted him/her for his slave master. Freedom allows mankind to live as God intended and gifted them to live.


My comments here only address the NT condemnation of slavery. Slavery in the OT is a whole another issue that I am unqualified to address.

The Law of Moses more accurately describes a system of laws that regulate a form of debt repayment. How exactly someone gets themselves into this problem of debt is not of concern anymore. For example, say you were promised 20 goats, 5 oxen, and 50 acres of land in return for 7 years of farm labor. You decided to do the 7 years with the hopes of giving your future offspring a respectable inheritance.
The laws favored Hebrew males more than Hebrew females and Gentiles. For Hebrew males the maximum amount of time in slavery against your will was 7 years. After a maximum of 7 years it was a choice.
Deuteronomy 15 and Exodus 21 contain the Laws Regarding Servants and Year of Release.
If you’re a male Gentile under the rule of Law of Moses slavery I recommend that you convert to Judaism and become a Hebrew. It would be the better option if you could survive the circumcision.
Regardless, the Law of Moses was not nearly as harsh as the Institutions of Slavery of America and Europe before the 20th century. That was completely without any choice and for someone’s entire life probably 99% of the time. The Law of Moses does not allow for slavery as it existed in the USA before the “war between the States.” The 13th Amendment that followed however is allowable under the Law of Moses.
